# Find distribution of time instants where a random signal assumes fixed value

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have a stationary and ergodic stochastic process $N(t,\omega)$. For a fixed $t^*$ I know the distribution of random variable $N(t^*,\omega)$.

Is there any way to know the distribution of time instants $(t_1, t_2, ... , t_n)$ in which $N(t,\omega) = N^*$ where $N^*$ is a scalar value?

I can limit observation to a fixed time interval.